# validate .net installation

Tags: .net-framework, validation

I need some tool that can validate .net installation (v2, v3, v3.5 etc.). I know that there is some kind of application I used it once. It validate all .net files and tell whether everything is ok.

Do you know the name of it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"This script will check the registry for the right versions of the .NET Framework 3.5, .NET Framework 3.0 SP1 & .NET Framework 2.0 SP1.  they are not there then it will return what it did find and let you know that an error happened."

[Source of Information](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/aaronru/net-framework-3-5-installation-validation-tool)